# how to convert joins query to laravel eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have query bulider's query like this

```
$schedule = DB::table('users')
        ->join('tblHomeCourts','users.homeCourtId','tblHomeCourts.homeCourtId')
        ->join('tblUserHomeCourts','tblUserHomeCourts.userId','users.userId')
        ->join('tblSchedules','tblUserHomeCourts.userHomeCourtId','tblSchedules.userHomeCourtId')
        ->select('tblHomeCourts.homeCourtName', 'tblHomeCourts.address','tblSchedules.timeFrom','tblSchedules.timeTo','tblSchedules.duration','tblSchedules.scheduleStatus','users.firstName','users.lastName','users.profilePic','users.userId')
        ->where(['tblSchedules.scheduleStatus'=> 0,
        ])->where('timeFrom','>',$request->currentTime)
        ->where('timeTo','>',$request->currentTime)
        ->where('tblUserHomeCourts.homeCourtId',$homeCourtId)
        ->get();
```

Now, I want to convert this into proper eloquent query using eloquent relationship I'm fully messed up with relationships can somebody please help me to find out the solution?

thanks :)

Comment: anybody here to answer??

Comment: Do you have the relationships defined in your models, already? If not, then start there, that's too much to write out for an answer defining all of those `belongsTo` and `hasMany` and `hasManyThrough`.

Comment: I have issues in relationships I've messed up I have defined the relationship in migration but in model I'm kinda confused.. please suggest me how to clear the confusion.

Comment: I would suggest [starting with the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) as it's pretty clear about the relationships. Then write unit tests to test those relationships. Fix the tests until the relationships all look good, then attempt your eloquent query.

Comment: yeah gone through that but I have confusion when it comes to 4 or more table joins.

Comment: there anyone???

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this we have to define relationships among the related table for the first place. Then we need to load the joint table using the `with` method.

For example you User model should look like this:

```
class User extends Model{
  protected $table = 'users';

  public function homeCourt(){
    //Many to one relation between user and homeCourt
    return $this->belongsTo(HomeCourt::class, 'homeCourtId', 'homeCourtId');
  }

  public function userHomeCourts(){
    //One to many relation between user nad userHomeCourt
    return $this->hasMany(UserHomeCourts::class, 'userId', 'userId');
  }
}
```

Your HomeCourt model should look like:

```
public class HomeCourt extends Model{
  protected $table = 'tblHomeCourts';

  public function user(){
    //One to many relation between homeCourt and user
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'homeCourtId', 'homeCourtId');
  }
}
```

Your UserHomeCourt model should look like:

```
public class UserHomeCourt extends Model{
  protected $table = 'tblUserHomeCourts'

  public function user(){
    //Many to one relation between userHomeCourts and users
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,  'userId', 'userId');
  }

  public function schedules(){
     //One to many relation between userHomeCourts and schedule
     return $this->hasMany(Schedule::class, 'userHomeCourtId', 'userHomeCourtId');
  }
}
```

Your Schedule model should look like:

```
public function Schedule extends Model{
  protected $table = 'tblSchedules';

  public function userHomeCourt(){
    //Many to one relation between schedule and userHomeCourts
    return $this->belongsTo(UserHomeCourt::class, 'userHomeCourtId', 'userHomeCourtId');
  }
}
```

Now you are ready to build your query. This query is bit different than the query you have built using query builder. Besides, the output of laravel eloquent query is also different. You have to adjust that result with you view:

You can query like this:

```
$users = User::with('homeCourt', 'userHomeCourts.schedule')->where('timeTo', '>', ,$request->currentTime)->get();
```

This query is just an example, you have to define it according to your requirement. Here, the parameters of with methods are the methods name of that `users` table relation with other tables. This is how it works.

You can read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships